# How to call loadmore function(only once) on scroll down javascript function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, scroll

i am using the following code to trigger my onloadmore funciton when user scroll down and reaches bottom of page. But i notice that many times the function get called multiple times on scroll down! could any one tell me why loadmore function get called more then once for same set of data! is it internet connection problem ? I just want loadmore called only once!

```
     <script>
var nextTagId = null;
       function callLoadMore() {

               $.ajax({
                type: "GET",

                dataType: "jsonp",

                cache: false,

                url: "http://api.sometime.com/api.php?count=100" + ( nextTagId ? "&next_id=" + nextTagId : ""),


        success: function(data) {

         for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

                    document.myform.outputtext.value = document.myform.outputtext.value+data.data[i].pics.standard.path+'\n' ;

                    }
                }

            });

        }
    </script>
<script>
        $(function() {
            $(window).bind("scroll", function (){ 
                console.log("SCROLL : " + $(window).scrollTop() 
                    + " - " + $(window).innerHeight() 
                    + " - " + document.body.clientHeight);
                if ($(window).scrollTop() + document.body.clientHeight >= $(window).innerHeight()) {
                            //alert('Bottom!');

                               callLoadMore();

                }
            });
        });
</script>
```